Таблица: Трансформирование 2 столбцов в одну строчку по очереди
Необходимо изменить вид таблицы автоматически. У меня сейчас сводная таблица выдает данные так: столбик "мастер" и столбик "число".  А мне нужно в строчку "мастер", "число", "мастер", "число", "мастер", "число" чтобы не сбивалась логика таблицы


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Укажите в тегах табличное приложение (Excel/Google Sheets) и приведите исходные данные.
